# How to use JSForce in Client side LWC in LWR

Tags: lightning-web-components, jsforce, lightning-web-runtime

I created a SPA application using LWR by following the steps mentioned in lwc.dev. 
I am trying to use this **App inside of Chrome Extension**. As part of this, i want to make some API Calls to salesforce for fetching some data. I am trying to use JSFORCE here. however after adding jsforce in the lwc code , i get the below error.

**Code in LWC**

```
import jsforce from 'jsforce';
```

> **Error Message**
> jsforce.js:22025 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: global is not
> defined

Comment: Open an issue via https://github.com/jsforce/jsforce/issues